# Android ARCore : Change the default gestures for translation and rotation

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am currently looking into the [sample sceneform app](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart) and I notice that when I run it, I can translate the model when I drag it with one finger and rotate it with two fingers.

What I want to do is the translation to be done when two fingers are on screen and moving, and the rotation with only one finger moving left/right.

Since the documentation for ARCore is currently not finished it is hard to figure it out on my own with the decompiled ARCore code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to provide an own [TransformationGestureDetector](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformationGestureDetector) for the TransformationSystem of the ArFragment. But that does not seem to be easily possible at the moment. So you would have to skip the ArFragment and use [ArSceneView](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ArSceneView) directly. That one behaves like a default Android View so you can use an onTouchListener and use a GestureDetector to detect the gestures. But in this case you have to do rotation and translation of your objects on your own.